# select join 2 tables and latest records of both tables

Tags: mysql, join, select, subquery

i have 2 tables board and hot. i need to select join latest records of both tables for each symbol_id

```sql
SELECT
    `board`.`id`,
    `board`.`symbol_id`,
    `board`.`symbol`,
    `board`.`t_volume`,
    `board`.`unix_timestamp`,
    `board`.`time`,
    `board`.`date`,
    `hot`.`id`,
    `hot`.`time`,
    `hot`.`date`,
    `hot`.`buy_repeat`,
    `hot`.`sell_repeat`
FROM `board` 
LEFT JOIN `hot`
    ON `hot`.`symbol_id` = `board`.`symbol_id`
WHERE  `board`.`unix_timestamp` = (
    SELECT `board`.`unix_timestamp`
    FROM `board`
    ORDER BY unix_timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
AND `board`.`symbol_id` = '34557241988629814'
GROUP BY `hot`.`symbol_id`
ORDER BY `hot`.`id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks detail (MySQL version, table declarations, sample data and expected output sample) but I think this is what you are looking for.

This is for MySQL < v8.0

The two sub-queries use the LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL technique to get the latest (by id) record per symbol_id. And then, as per your attempt, the derived tables are LEFT JOINed.

```sql
SELECT

    `b_latest`.`id`,
    `b_latest`.`symbol_id`,
    `b_latest`.`symbol`,
    `b_latest`.`t_volume`,
    `b_latest`.`unix_timestamp`,
    `b_latest`.`time`,
    `b_latest`.`date`,

    `h_latest`.`id`,
    `h_latest`.`time`,
    `h_latest`.`date`,
    `h_latest`.`buy_repeat`,
    `h_latest`.`sell_repeat`

FROM (
    SELECT
        `b1`.`id`,
        `b1`.`symbol_id`,
        `b1`.`symbol`,
        `b1`.`t_volume`,
        `b1`.`unix_timestamp`,
        `b1`.`time`,
        `b1`.`date`
    FROM board b1
    LEFT JOIN board b2 ON (b1.symbol_id = b2.symbol_id AND b1.id < b2.id)
    WHERE b2.id IS NULL
) AS b_latest
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        `h1`.`id`,
        `h1`.`symbol_id`
        `h1`.`time`,
        `h1`.`date`,
        `h1`.`buy_repeat`,
        `h1`.`sell_repeat`
    FROM hot h1
    LEFT JOIN hot h2 ON (h1.symbol_id = h2.symbol_id AND h1.id < h2.id)
    WHERE h2.id IS NULL
) AS h_latest
    ON b_latest.symbol_id = h_latest.symbol_id
```

For MySQL 8.0 and onwards you can use [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) -

```sql
WITH `b_latest` AS (
    SELECT
        `b1`.`id`,
        `b1`.`symbol_id`,
        `b1`.`symbol`,
        `b1`.`t_volume`,
        `b1`.`unix_timestamp`,
        `b1`.`time`,
        `b1`.`date`,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `symbol_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC) AS `rn`
    FROM `board` `b1`
), `h_latest` AS (
    SELECT
        `h1`.`id`,
        `h1`.`symbol_id`
        `h1`.`time`,
        `h1`.`date`,
        `h1`.`buy_repeat`,
        `h1`.`sell_repeat`,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `symbol_id` ORDER BY `id` DESC) AS `rn`
    FROM `hot` `h1`
)
SELECT

    `b_latest`.`id`,
    `b_latest`.`symbol_id`,
    `b_latest`.`symbol`,
    `b_latest`.`t_volume`,
    `b_latest`.`unix_timestamp`,
    `b_latest`.`time`,
    `b_latest`.`date`,

    `h_latest`.`id`,
    `h_latest`.`time`,
    `h_latest`.`date`,
    `h_latest`.`buy_repeat`,
    `h_latest`.`sell_repeat`

FROM `b_latest`
LEFT JOIN `h_latest`
    ON `b_latest`.`symbol_id` = `h_latest`.`symbol_id`
    AND `h_latest`.`rn` = 1
WHERE `b_latest`.`rn` = 1
```